# Remote App will not authenticate with SAML Claims

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth

We have a web application that integrates with Sharepoint 2013, in essence it uses SP to store documents.

In dev and test, where we've not used a federated provider, the web app authenticates without any issues.

In pre-prod, the first environment with SAML claims, it doesn't work

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUri))
{
 .....
 context.ExecuteQuery();
 .....
}
```

The minute it hits the ExecuteQuery line it throws the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

And this is, as far as I can tell, the problem from SP logs:

```
w3wp.exe .. SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization .. The user is not authenticated, send access denied. NullUser=False, NullIdentity=False, IsAuthenticated=False    cc51049d-a55a-e02b-95fa-10a7b3c887b4
```

The code just lists the contents of a folder inside a library.

Going through directly to the SharePoint site, I can log on with the service account (account used to integrate with SP) without any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bump! This would be very helpful for me as well. I assume this is using default credentials but it seems like we need to add some more stuff to the query (fedAuth token) but we haven't been able to accomplish that successfully.